# Nhibernate in asp,net ISession help

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, isession

We're using nhibernate in and asp.net MVC application.

We are implementing the Session per Request pattern, via a httpModule.

It looks pretty straight forward, but when we run with NHibernate Profiler, it clearly shows that the 
sessions are never getting closed.

the pattern seems straight forward...but I don't understand why the sessions are never closing.

here's the code i think is important.

set up the event handler:

```
    context.EndRequest += new EventHandler(this.context_EndRequest);
```

in the handler dispose the Session

```
private void context_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            netLogHdl.ArchDebug("NHibernateHttpModule.context_EndRequest() ");

            Dispose(0);// we are hitting 2 dbs and thus keep one session for each.
            Dispose(1);

            HttpContextBuildPolicy.DisposeAndClearAll();
        }


private void Dispose(int sessionIndex)
        {
            netLogHdl.ArchStart("NHibernateHttpModule.Dispose", "int sessionIndex=\" + sessionIndex + \")");

            try
            {
                //close the DB session
                string sessManagerName = "";
                string jcdcManager = "JCDC Manager";
                string spamisManager = "Spamis Manager";

                if (sessionIndex == 0)
                    sessManagerName = jcdcManager;
                else
                {
                    sessManagerName = spamisManager;
                }


                ISession oneSession = sessionPerDB[sessionIndex];
                if (oneSession != null)
                {
                    if (sessManagerName == jcdcManager) netLogHdl.ArchDebug(sessManagerName + " oneSession is NOT null");

                    if (oneSession.IsOpen)
                    {
                        // Don't flush - all saves should use transactions and calling Commit does the flush.
                        if (sessManagerName == jcdcManager) netLogHdl.ArchDebug(sessManagerName + " Closing the session");

                        //This will overrite it with the exact same session, if they don't match something weird is going on - EWB
                        oneSession = CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(factoryPerDB[sessionIndex]);
                        oneSession.Close();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (sessManagerName == jcdcManager) netLogHdl.ArchDebug(sessManagerName + " Session is NOT open");
                    }

                    //if ( sessManagerName == jcdcManager ) netLogHdl.ArchDebug( sessManagerName + " Session got Dispose()-ing" );
                    //oneSession.Dispose();
                }
                else
                {
                    if (sessManagerName == jcdcManager) netLogHdl.ArchDebug(sessManagerName + " Session is NULL");
                }

                sessionPerDB[sessionIndex] = null;

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }


            netLogHdl.ArchEnd();
        }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? What shoud I look at, is the pattern not implemented correclty?

I'm flummoxed

Thanks!

E-

Comment: In a comment in the above code, it says "Don't flush - all saves should use transactions and calling Commit does the flush.
", but the code is neither flushing nor using transactions. I think thats a problem.

Comment: Transaction are not same as session, he is probably handling it outside of the http module, just like I am. It is Session-Per-Request, not Transaction-Per-Request.

Comment: Yes transactions are being commited outside of this layer.
I did jsut add a flush, right before the close incase a session was'nt using a transaction for some reason (ie a fetch)

Answer (score 1):

You should call dispose and not disconnect or close. System.IDisposable implementing objects should always be disposed by calling the dispose method, or by a using block.

Comment: I am now doing a belt and suspenders approach

oneSession = CurrentSessionContext.Unbind( factoryPerDB[ sessionIndex ] );
oneSession.Flush();
oneSession.Close();
oneSession.Dispose();

No joy, I still have eternal sessions.

Comment: Than the errror is somewhere in the parts of the code I don't know about.

Answer (score 0):

You also might want to have a look at the code on [Ben Day's blog post](http://blog.benday.com/archive/2005/03/16/198.aspx) about session management.