# Nhibernate Session and ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, isession

Using NhibernateProfiler we have determined that we are creating an ISession for every http request.    However the  ISessions  never close.    We can see in the log where localSession.Close()  fires.    Is there something in our config file that would cause the session to never close?    Are there any other reasons   localSession.Close()  would not physical close the session?    We are on 2.1 of NHibernate.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.provider">JCDCHelper.DAL.Utilities.JCDCConnectionProvider, JCDCHelper.DAL</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.Sybase</property>
    <property name="connection.release_mode">on_close</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">JCDCHelper.DAL.Utilities.DataDirectSybaseDriver, JCDCHelper.DAL</property>
    <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string_name">ProdSybase</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">web</property>
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
```

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Dubplicate of your of question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835244/nhibernate-in-asp-net-isession-help

Comment: Yeah my boss wanted to ask the question in a different way as well... sorry.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointy-Haired_Boss

Answer (score 0):

Are you Disposing the ISession?  Wrapping it in a using statement?

Comment: using a httpModule to close it on the end of the request

oneSession = CurrentSessionContext.Unbind( factoryPerDB[ sessionIndex ] );
oneSession.Flush();
oneSession.Close();